# browser functions not working inside callback function in protractor

Tags: javascript, mysql, callback, protractor

I have been working on protractor for over two weeks now and have taken a liking towards it, but there's a certain problem that's been bugging me for a while:

What I want to do is: fetch values from database and use it in my tests, so I have been doing the following:

```
var test=function(callback)
{
//connection made;
//select query fired;

connection.query('select * from mytable', function(rows,error){

var result={};

for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
{
result.first=rows[i].col1;
result.sec=rows[i].col2;
result.third=rows[i].col3;

callback(result);
}


});

} 


//and then I use the return values as:

test(function(data){

var value1;
var value2;
value1=data.first;
value2=data.sec;
// i am able to print value1 and value2, the real problem is below:

browser.get(value1);//the browser function wont work!!

});
```

the spec passes with no failures,
I can print the values from the database but I am not able to use the browser functions.

Kindly help!!

Comment: What test framework are you using? Mocha or Jasmine.

Comment: hi, i am using jasmine framework

Comment: what is `value1`? It has to be a proper constructed url

Comment: @rojosa,  check the type of _value1_ variable. You can do it with **console.log(typeof value1)**_.

Comment: yes, it is a properly constructed url, value1 is https://www.google.co.in/

Comment: also, when i use the browser.sleep function outside the test function, browser.get works but after given seconds the test ends without executing the rest of the functions of the test function.

Comment: I'm assuming you passed it the full URL, including the http://?  i.e. `https://www.google.co.in/`

Comment: @Gunderson , yes it fetches the full URL.

Comment: Copy value1 output and navigate to that URL to test.  
Which browser are you using? Could you post your config file?